# mmenu jQuery plugin doesn't update url on clicking links with href starting with #

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-plugins, mmenu, routerjs

```
<li><span>About</span>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#/history">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="#/address">Our address</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I am using [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) plugin. Following links does not update window location. I am using backbone.js and want to launch separate modules with the help of router. But unfortunately mmenu is not enabling links to update the window.location

Answer (score 0):

If you start any link with `#` tag it will redirect to any page. You can use it without `#` tag like this

```
<ul>
       <li><a href="/history">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="/address">Our address</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Sometimes we need to link some `a` to some div it that cases we use `#` tag for example

```
<ul>
       <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="#address">Our address</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Above code will work when there will be any element with ID's `history` or `address` and will take the page to that element but for updating URL you need to remove `#` tag

Comment: These links does updates the url if i use them anywhere apart from mmenu. I want them to work in mmenu as well.

Comment: Check if is there any code like `preventDefault` used on click of the links. If yes then it will not work with `#` tag :)

Comment: removing # will make them links to another page. I want them to work as anchor. By using these links as anchors i can route through different modules using backbone's router.

Comment: please share your code as i need to check is there any use of `preventDefault` function because it prevents any tag from its default functionality may be this would be the reason the link is not added to URL

Comment: Gaurav, I am not using `preventDefault` method in my code. It might have been used in mmenu library. But why is it that links without `#` are working correctly?

Comment: Anyways I used another workaround for this by binding click on links after creating mmenu. I am updating the url there.